# How to find words from list of words in another list

Tags: python-3.x

For example,I have this list of words :

```
words = ['foo','doo']
```

and I want to find them in list of words that look like this :

```
text = ['<p>foo','one','two','rgb(0,0,0);">dupa</span></p>']
```

What i want to do exacly is to wrap every word from the first list with an html tag like `<strong></strong>`

As far as i know i should do some sort of loop :

```
for word in text:
    if word in words:
        do something here
```

But i do not know how to wrap every word with tags. Any help would be nice !

Comment: So, should the `foo` in `'<p>foo'` be wrapped in a tag, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression, matching the disjunction of all those words, and replace them with the same word wrapped in tags.

Something like this:

```
import re
p = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(words))
for word in text:
    print p.sub(r"<tag>\1</tag>", word)
```

Or in case you want to create a new list:

```
text_new = [p.sub(r"<tag>\1</tag>", word) for word in text]
```